# How to overcome problem with dblink when one server is unavailable

Tags: postgresql, connection, dblink

I create a view like this

```
 CREATE view  zaliha as
    SELECT * FROM public.dblink
('meteor','SELECT z.skladiste,ar.sifra,z.velicina,z.kolicina,z.rezervacija,z.kolicina - z.rezervacija
 as raspolozivo
 from zaliha z, artikli ar
 where ar.id=z.artikal
 and (kolicina <> 0 or kolicina <> 0)') 
AS DATA(skladiste CHARACTER VARYING, sifra CHARACTER VARYING, velicina CHARACTER VARYING, kolicina NUMERIC,
        rezervacija NUMERIC, raspolozivo NUMERIC)

        union

SELECT * FROM public.dblink
('dorcol','SELECT z.skladiste,ar.sifra,z.velicina,z.kolicina,z.rezervacija,z.kolicina - z.rezervacija
 as raspolozivo
 from zaliha z, artikli ar
 where ar.id=z.artikal
 and (kolicina <> 0 or kolicina <> 0)') 
AS DATA(skladiste CHARACTER VARYING, sifra CHARACTER VARYING, velicina CHARACTER VARYING, kolicina NUMERIC,
        rezervacija NUMERIC, raspolozivo NUMERIC)

        union

SELECT * FROM public.dblink
('uzice','SELECT z.skladiste,ar.sifra,z.velicina,z.kolicina,z.rezervacija,z.kolicina - z.rezervacija
 as raspolozivo
 from zaliha z, artikli ar
 where ar.id=z.artikal
 and (kolicina <> 0 or kolicina <> 0)') 
AS DATA(skladiste CHARACTER VARYING, sifra CHARACTER VARYING, velicina CHARACTER VARYING, kolicina NUMERIC,
        rezervacija NUMERIC, raspolozivo NUMERIC)
```

In fact this is union of 3 same select, but from different servers. What I need, is that I get result of all availables servers, and if there is error with 1 servers, that result to exclude. For example, server meteor and dorcol are available, and server uzice is not, I wanna this view result only of meteor and dorcol, and exclude error with uzice.

ERROR when one server is not available is:

```
ERROR:  could not establish connection

    DETAIL:  could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "x.x.x.x" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Capture the error and run a statement that does not access the table on the broken connection.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Can please help me with this example?

Comment: You are computing a `UNION` of three tables. Now if a `SELECT` on the first fails, calculate only a `UNION` of the other two, and so on. It means three tests and a lot of `IF` conditions and 7 different queries, but it can be done.

Comment: How often do servers appear and disappear?  If you ping a server and it is there, is it likely to stay there throughout the duration of your query?

Comment: @jjanes this was only example. I have running over 40th servers. It is always another one, problem is that 40 servers is not on one location, they are spread. And dont have all stable connection

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a view, but you can do it with a set returning function.

I've changed it to use pgbench_branches table for simplicity.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fail_tolerant()                                                                                                        
 RETURNS SETOF pgbench_branches
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$ 
declare 
connections text[]='{host=127.0.0.1,host=192.168.0.bad}';
conn text;  
begin 
  foreach conn in array connections loop 
    begin
      return query SELECT * FROM public.dblink (conn,'SELECT * from pgbench_branches') AS DATA(bid integer, bbalance integer, filler character(88));
    EXCEPTION when others then          
       RAISE NOTICE 'exception caught';
    END;
  end loop;
end $function$;
```

This doesn't do the de-duplication feature of UNION, so you would want to add that separately:

```
select distinct * from fail_tolerant();
```

You would probably want to do better logging than what I do here.  If any connection attempts gets black-holed, rather than accepted or rejected immediately, this could take a long time to complete.  So you might want to set a connect_timeout in each connection string.